# Rによるパネルデータを使ったplmによる分析について、「システムは数値的に特異です: 条件数の逆数 = 5.4087e-18」とエラー表示された際の対応について

Tags: r

Rのパッケージplmを使い、企業の業績などのクロスセクション、時系列のパネルデータを分析しています。
次のようなコマンドです。

```
result<-plm(売上高~市場規模+流動比率+R&D比率,data=sample,model="within")
summary(result)
```

説明変数が1つの場合は動作するのですが、説明変数が2つになると動作する時としない時があり、
動作しない時は次のエラーが出ます。

> 「システムは数値的に特異です: 条件数の逆数 = 5.4087e-18」

調べると、説明変数の方がサンプル数よりも多いのでは？という書き込みもありましたが、
企業数（n）=62社、サンプル数＝434、なので問題はなさそうです。

このような場合の対処法についてご存知の方がいればご教示いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

どのようなデーターを用いているのか不明なので回答できませんが、
R.jp Wikiに事例が載っています。
あなたのデーターと付き合わせてみてはいかがでしょうか。

[http://www.okadajp.org/RWiki/?統計手法の実地への適用限界](http://www.okadajp.org/RWiki/?%E7%B5%B1%E8%A8%88%E6%89%8B%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E5%9C%B0%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E9%81%A9%E7%94%A8%E9%99%90%E7%95%8C)